# how to design architecture of mobile android application

Tags: android, architecture

I am starting one application ,this applications runs in iPhone, android, windows and web based. How can implement total starting to ending architecture all requirement and functional  requirements.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional Documentation: It should work.

Architectural Documentation: It should also work.

Design: The client should call a server that gives back some data, which is then shown on the client.

---

Actually, in all seriousness, you want to use a client-server design. Write your backend as a web service (REST is best!) and call it from each client. Each client will have to be separately written, but you can share the service and data tier. Such an undertaking is immense and beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: please sending some sample pdf